# Integrate Facebook login and register

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, authentication

The site already has php login and register, but it has to have facebook login and register too. Making them separate - I can do that, but making them combined - I'm confused about it.

I mean, if someone click login and facebook, but his facebook email is already registred in the system with the basic system(not the facebook one), the person should get an error message, right?

Can someone give me some advice how to integrate the facebook login with the basic php login, so I don't mess up the code or the database?

Comment: Break the task up into a flow chart and it’ll come apparent to you how to program it.

Comment: You just have to check if the email already exists in the database once the user is logged : if it already exists, you just have to load his data and/or his credentials. Generally, we count Facebook connection as something safe and accept to log the user even if he didn't register via Facebook. StackOverFlow is using this system for example.

If you want a good tutorial about how to integrate Facebook signup/login via its PHP SDK, Facebook Github account provides a nice example : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4